# Jmeter is not recording the page where "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" is present

Tags: html, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I was trying to record a webpage using Jmeter tool. 
Functionality : The webpage collects data and send it to the server when "SUBMIT" is clicked.
During Recording : The webpage only refreshes itself without sending any data to the server.

Investigation : The webpage contains the following Request Header- 
------WebKitFormBoundaryBuGANZEvO85y5f29
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$CP1$fileExteneralRecords"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Inference : It is observed that whenever we try to record a page which contains this "Content-Type: application/octet-stream", we are facing the same problem. 
Can anybody help us in recording the webpage where this content type is appearing? Any kind of suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to upload a file. JMeter can record this kind of events, however you need to put the file(s) under JMeter's "working directory" - usually /bin folder -  so it could pick them up during recording and replay.

See [JMeter Bug 48479](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48479) for detailed explanation and [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for a set of recommendations on proper simulation of file uploads/downloads in your JMeter test.

Comment: I am not uploading anything... Maybe the upload option is there, but it is not compulsory.... Is there a way to bypass this part so that jmeter will be able to record the event.

Comment: Try out [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I also observed same issue and resolved by

1. recording http sampler by some other means like blazemeter, fiddler, saving as HAR and converting to jmx.
2. Just select "use multipartform-data for POST" option of http sampler and remove "content-type" parameter from its header

   referring link:- [How to send a POST request a file with Content-Type: application/octet-stream in Node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490344/how-to-send-a-post-request-a-file-with-content-type-application-octet-stream-in)